# How do you use any2mobi command line tool (part of Calibre) to make mobi files from HTML?

Tags: macos, file-conversion, kindle, calibre

I am on MAC OS X 10.5.5. I installed Calibre, a tool for converting e-book files from one format to another. It has a GUI as well as command line tools. I am trying to run the command line tool "any2mobi" to convert HTML files to MOBI pocket format or Kindle AZW format, with a TOC.

I get the error "-bash: any2mobi: command not found". Clearly, any2mobi is not in my path. Where is it? I tried searching but came up empty.

I installed version 0.6.0b6 of Calibre.

Answer (score 2):

From [the calibre download page](http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/download_osx):

1. Before trying to use the command line tools, you must run the app at least once. This will ask you for you password and then setup the symbolic links for the command line tools.
2. The app cannot be run from within the dmg. You must drag it to a folder on your filesystem (The Desktop, Applications, wherever).
3. In order for localization of the user interface in your language, select your language in the preferences (by pressing u8+P) and select your language.

Have you done all three of these?

Comment: Yes, I have copied the application into my Applications/Utilities directory and run it.

In which directory would these symbolic links be found?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I got here with the same problem and could not find a solution here. So...

I was having similar problem (but on Ubuntu), and after some [google-fu](http://www.mobileread.mobi/forums/showthread.php?t=101053), I've been told that:

> That applies to old versions of Calibre. Now all the conversion logic
>   is subsumed into "ebook-convert".

And at least in Ubuntu, ebook-convert is on the path.
Hope I could help someone.